# In Spring, is it possible to use @Value to inject a String JNDI value from java:global?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jndi

I know that you can use @Value to inject a String from java:comp/env like this:

```
@Value("${someCompEnvKey}")
private String myJavaCompEnvValue;
```

But what if I have a value like "java:global/aDifferentKey"?

Can someone help me understand what I would need to do configuration-wise to make this happen?